# Best encrypting-decrypting algorithm in JAVA for data exahange using XML b/w two systems

Tags: java, encryption

My requirement is to find best algorithm use to secure data sent using XML over network.  This is important data which is to be exchanged between third parties.

I know about DES which is quite outdated these days. MD5 appeared as another option but this does not allow decryption to get data back(please correct me if I am wrong)

What other options do we have to accomplish above task and which is best and most standard way to do it?

Tried out AES, it uses common key for encryption and decryption. Other option I explored was RSA, which has two keys public and private, for encryption and decryption.

Not able to decide about better approach of above two.

Comment: what do you mean over network?  will https work?  or do you mean you need to store an XML file on disk and then send it like email or ftp?

Comment: Let me explain you whole scenario, We have an application. Now, requirememnt is to integrate it with some third party applications for exchanging data. Since data is very important we need to ensure its safety. I am looking for options available and analyzing which ever suits us best. Looked at Cryptix also, seems no development in it since long time. Please share your views

Comment: You haven't answered the question. What's wrong with HTTPS?

Comment: @EJP not sure how I can use https to encrypt xml files. As I emntioned earlier, the two systems are disintegrated and both may not support HTTPS.  Would really appreciate if you can be more clear with approach.

Comment: @Mayank I think you need to be more clear with your question. Practically every computer system in existence supports SSL and HTTPS these days, and these are the standard methods for encryption over networks. If you want to achieve something different, you need to say so.

Comment: @EJP, Thanks for input. I agree that we have HTTPS as one of the most widely used standard protocol for secure data exchange using HTTP protocol. In my next project I am required to have communication between third party applications using XML/web services. I was exploring options available to me.  I came across few choices, AES, RSA and HTTTPS as you mentioned. I will now analyze above three options and will answer the question based on my research, as all three are acceptable formats for encryption and will have their pros and cons. I would appreciate if you could share your views on same.

Comment: @Mayank I didn't say HTTPS was a 'format for encryption', so you can't 'agree' with it. It is a protocol encompassing one of many encryption formats including the others you name and also encompassing message integrity and peer authentication as well as privacy.

Comment: @EJP, I understand that HTTPS is secure HTTP protocol as stated in my above comment initially. I did not realize  that I mentioned it with encryption formats later in my comment. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Advanced Encryption Standard(AES).[The differences between AES and DES](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/answer/The-differences-between-AES-and-DES)

Answer (score 0):

There's a W3C standard for this, it's called [XML Encryption Syntax and Processing](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlenc-core/), which uses a cipher like a DES/3DES-CBC symmetric key cipher.